# Chart.js automatic chosen scale value

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using automatic scale starting value. It will generate and chose  min and max number in y axis automatically. Now i am facing problem, The scale start exactly from the min number and will be finish exactly from the max number. Can i set the scale to start before the min number like 2% of the value? This is my chart: [image]

I just want to notice that i have random values, so i can not adjust the scale to start and end certain values!
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use **`min`** and **`max`** property of y-axis ticks, to set a minimum *(start)* and maximum *(end)* scale value respectively.

```
scales: {
   yAxes: [{
      ticks: {
         min: Math.min.apply(this, data_array) - 5,
         max: Math.max.apply(this, data_array) + 5
      }
   }]
}
```

**ᴅᴇᴍᴏ**

```js
var data_array = [20, 22, 24, 28, 30];

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'BAR',
         data: data_array,
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.5)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               min: Math.min.apply(this, data_array) - 5,
               max: Math.max.apply(this, data_array) + 5,
               stepSize: 5
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: I have to  pick different value's number in my chart. So i can not limit the max and min number. for example the should take the min number automatically then start before 5 degrees ..Thanks for your help

Comment: You can easily calculate that, NO big deal. Do you have separate array for data values?

Comment: Yes, I  do. But could you please tell me how to calculate that?

Comment: Great  it's working now. and i have small issue left. if i could make with percent of the value `min: Math.min.apply(this, arrData[i]) - 2%,`? thank you so much for your help..

Comment: Yes you can, using - `Math.min.apply(this, data_array) - (Math.min.apply(this, data_array) * 2 / 100)`, but that'll look ugly tho, as you might sometimes get floating point numbers.

Comment: There is a grace function in chart.js. In your axis take just add grace:"2%".

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the GRUNT answer.

```
function round(x) { 
    return Math.ceil(x / 5) * 5; 
}

min: round(Math.min.apply(this, data_array) - 5),
max: round(Math.max.apply(this, data_array) + 5),
```

This will make the chart more beautiful if your stepSize is 5.